# Text-to-speech from recognition result

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am using the TextToSpeech class in order to make the system speak.
Firstly I speak something through the voice recognizer and set the text to a  textView. Next I want the system to speak what I've spoken earlier.
I find that the first step is working successfully but I don't hear anything after I speak.

My code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int REQUEST_CODE=1;
    TextView text;
    ImageButton button;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private Button ttsButton;
    private ArrayList<String> results;
    private String s;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


            button=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);


                    }
        });

        textToSpeech =new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            }
        });
        textToSpeech.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);


    }

    public void onPause(){
        if(textToSpeech !=null){
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
             s=results.get(0);
            text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(""+results.get(0));


        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to trigger TTS engine after activity result :-

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
             s=results.get(0);
            text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(""+results.get(0));

          //Trigger text to speech here
            textToSpeech.speak(results.get(0), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: also comment onPause you are stopping TTS engine in onPause and onPuse will be called every time voice input dialog will open.